# Stateless EJB and clustering

Tags: java, ejb

scenario:
EjbA and EjbB are both remote stateless session beans.

```
@Stateless
public class EjbA
{
  @EJB
  private EjbB b;

  public void foo(){
    b.method1();
    b.method1();
    b.method2();
  }
}
```

Is it correct that any of these method calls on b
can happen on a different node/VM in a clustered environment?

Even the calls to method1?

I mean if some client calls method foo, can it happen that 
in the this transaction method1 is called on node1
and the next call to method1, during the same invocation of foo(), 
goes to an Ejb instance on node2?

Interpreting the following quote from "Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1":

"... each invocation upon a SLSB proxy operates independently from 
those both before and after. In fact, its underlying bean instances
may be swapped interchangeably between requests."

I would say yes.

Is there any way to ensure that these calls happen to the same stateless session bean instance on the same node/VM?

If I am right with my first assumption, it should not be possible.

E.g. using a singleton only ensures that an Ejb is unique per VM.
So in a clustered environment it doesn't give me this guarentee.

Comment: updated my answer. If you still have questions it might help to describe the behavior you're trying to achieve.

Comment: the [Singleton Interface] (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html) combined with using only [Local Interfaces] (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html#gipmz)  will guarantee all requests are handled by the same Stateless Session Bean on a local / co-located VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct that any of these method calls on b can happen on a
>   different node/VM in a clustered environment?

Yes, method calls can be remote - so long as you have [properly setup the remote interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html#gipiu) on EjbB

> Even the calls to method1?
>
> I mean if some client calls method foo, can it happen that in the this
>   transaction method1 is called on node1 and the next call to method1,
>   during the same invocation of foo(), goes to an Ejb instance on node2?
>
> Interpreting the following quote from "Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1":
>
> "... each invocation upon a SLSB proxy operates independently from
>   those both before and after. In fact, its underlying bean instances
>   may be swapped interchangeably between requests."
>
> I would say yes.

I 100% agree with your assessment. In fact, container implementors are free to create and destroy Stateless Session Beans on each method invocation -- they are independent from eachother.

> Is there any way to ensure that these calls happen to the same
>   stateless session bean instance

You'd have to make the EJB a [@Singleton](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html). That way you ensure that it's only created once per [EJB Container Classloader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html)

> on the same node/VM?

Yes you can make sure all calls are local - do not define a remote interface. [By default all EJBs only expose local interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html#gipmz); meaning if you don't do any extra work - you're always calling local EJBs.

There's no reliable way to "force" independent method calls to be handled by the same Stateless Bean. If you're trying to maintain a "conversational state" between EjbA and EjbB then this is what the [Stateful Session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjg.html#gipnl) bean is for. With a Stateful Session Bean, the method invocations are not only guaranteed to be handled by the the same bean but EjbB will be able to remember state between the method calls from EjbA. In this setup EjbB would be completely dedicated to the specific instance of EjbA and would not serve any other clients until EjbA ends the session - by being destroyed for example.

Comment: Sry, my question wasn't asked very well.
Please see my updated post.